# How to get old rabbitmq events into new services?

Tags: python-3.x, rabbitmq, pika

for my backend micro-service application i am using RabbitMq as the message broker.

For the existing services i am getting events well. My question is how to pull all the old events into a new micro-service which would launch in future.

Just consider if there are three services currently

1. Product
2. Notification
3. Order

if i created a new product it information will be broadcasted to Notification service as well as Order service. So a record of product will be there in both Notification and Order.

so, after a while(when around 500+ products where added), if i had created new service called Analytic’s and wanted all the product created events to be listened when it is initially up.

I am using Python, RabbitMQ & Pika library.

this is my sample code

Sample Publisher code

```
import pika
import sys, random

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.URLParameters('<rabbitmq-link>'))
channel = connection.channel()
channel.exchange_declare(exchange='group', exchange_type='fanout')


message = "info: Hello World!"

channel.basic_publish(exchange='group', routing_key='', body=message)

print(" [x] Sent %r" % message)
connection.close()
```

Service one code

```
import pika

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.URLParameters('<rabbitmq-link>'))
channel = connection.channel()

channel.exchange_declare(exchange='group', exchange_type='fanout')

result = channel.queue_declare(queue='group-1', exclusive=False)
queue_name = result.method.queue

channel.queue_bind(exchange='group', queue=queue_name)

print(' [*] Waiting for logs. To exit press CTRL+C')

def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    print(" [x] %r" % body)

channel.basic_consume(queue=queue_name, on_message_callback=callback, auto_ack=True)

channel.start_consuming()
```

Service two code

```
import pika

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.URLParameters('<rabbitmq-link>'))
channel = connection.channel()

channel.exchange_declare(exchange='group', exchange_type='fanout')

result = channel.queue_declare(queue='group-2', exclusive=False)
queue_name = result.method.queue

channel.queue_bind(exchange='group', queue=queue_name)

print(' [*] Waiting for logs. To exit press CTRL+C')

def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    print(" [x] %r" % body)

channel.basic_consume(queue=queue_name, on_message_callback=callback, auto_ack=True)

channel.start_consuming()
```

So, i want a way where when i made the third service live, it should be able to triggered by old events